# Can't instantiate abstract class RootMeanSquaredError

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm working my way through Chollet's "Deep Learning with Python". I've been doing some implementations and I got stuck on this. I thought I mistyped something, but it doesn't appear so.

Does anyone have a clue on what may be going on?

```
model = get_mnist_model()
model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop",
    loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
    metrics=["accuracy", RootMeanSquaredError()])
model.fit(train_images, train_labels,
    epochs=3,
    validation_data=(val_images, val_labels))

test_metrics = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)
```

> TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class RootMeanSquaredError with
> abstract methods result

Answer (score 0):

I just got this error too and realized that it was because I defined the `result` and `reset_state` methods in new code blocks in the Jupyter notebook. Once I moved them into the same block as the `RootMeanSquaredError` class definition, the code you posted worked fine without triggering the TypeError.

This should have been obvious but it wasn't until I saw [this example](https://keras.io/api/metrics/#as-subclasses-of-metric-stateful) that I realized they belong to the class definition.